# Print sets of lines that do not have a corresponding pair

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, perl

I am trying to print set of two lines that do not have a corresponding pair. I ultimately want to remove these lines.

### Example:

```
NM00123_rn5_0_1_2
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
NM00123_mm10_0_1_2
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
NM00124_rn5_0_1_3
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
NM00124_mm10_0_1_3
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
NM00125_rn5_0_1_4
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
NM00126_rn5_0_1_5
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRr
NM00126_mm10_0_1_5
RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
```

The line starting with NM are headers and the next line is made of sequence of alphabets. The header lines for a pair match in all positions except for rn5 and mm10. I want to only retain sets of four lines were the NM header digits before and after rn5 and mm10 match for a pair. So from the above example: Header in line 1 for rn5 matches Header in line 3 for mm10 so keep that....but Header for rn5 at line 9 does not have a corresponding pair so print both the header and the next line with the sequence. I want finally to have a file of equal number of rn5 and mm10 entries.

I am very new to using Unix and would really appreciate help to do this. Thank you.

### Expected outcome:

All the above entries sans the line without a corresponding pair. In this case:

```
NM00125_rn5_0_1_4
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Comment: Please add expected output... and read the [editing help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a somewhat involved version for awk. Some differences from the sed version from steeldriver:

1. It makes no assumptions about the ordering of the `mm10` or `rn5` records
2. It can deal with a missing `rn5` record
3. It will output the unmatched records to `stderr`.
4. It is a lot more code :-)

It can be run with:

```
awk -f my_program.awk infile
```

The code:

```
# find and store a header
/^NM.*/ { header = $0; next }

# we found an mm10 line
header ~ /_rn5/ {

    # get the mm10 line that matches this rn5
    mm_match = header
    sub("_rn5", "_mm10", mm_match)

    # if we have a previous mm10, then print the pair
    if (mm_match in headers) {
        print header
        print
        print mm_match
        print headers[mm_match]

        delete headers[mm_match]
    } else {
        headers[header] = $0
    }
    next
}

# we found an mm10 line
header ~ /_mm10/ {

    # get the rn5 line that matches this mm10
    mm_match = header
    sub("_mm10", "_rn5", mm_match)

    # if we have a previous rn5, then print the pair
    if (mm_match in headers) {
        print mm_match
        print headers[mm_match]
        print header
        print

        delete headers[mm_match]
    } else {
        headers[header] = $0
    }
    next
}
```

Additionally this code can be added to the end of the file to output any unmatched lines to `standard error`:

```
# The END block is here just to output anything that was unmatched
END {
    # dump the unmatched to stderr
    for (header in headers) {
        print header > "/dev/stderr"
        print headers[header] > "/dev/stderr"
    }
}
```

It can be run with:

```
awk -f my_program.awk infile > outfile 2> unmatched
```

Which will output the requested output (via standard out) into `outfile`, and will output the leftover input (via standard error) into `unmatched`.  For the details of I/O redirection in all its variety, see the chapter on [Redirections](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) in the Bash reference manual.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. However, there are a few things I don't understand. The output file is the "unmatched" file, right? And that is supposed to have the entries that do not have a matching pair ? Currently, Unmatched contains all of the entries from infile but the order  is messed up.  Outfile 2 exactly does what? The outfile generated is empty. Sorry, if my questions are too basic. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: I restructured the answer to put the complication of the unmatched case as optional.  See if that helps with your understanding.  If not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're asking for is something that

- maintains a 4-line buffer; and
- if the thing following `rn5` (up to the next newline) matches the thing following `mm10` (up to the next-but-two newline) print it and start over

It's probably an ugly way to do it, but to illustrate with GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -n -e :a \
         -e '$!N; /rn5_\(.*\)\n.*\n.*mm10_\1\n/ {p;b}' \
         -e '/.*\n.*\n.*\n/ D' \
         -e ba infile > outfile

$ diff outfile infile
8a9,10
> NM00125_rn5_0_1_4
> zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```